# What is the right RxJava operator to do this?

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

What is the right RxJava operator for the following scenario :

I want to check if I have a token stored, if not get it from the network and use it to perform another network request.

I think it should be done with `and/then/when` or with a combination of `filter` and `flatMap` but not sure how.

Comment: Note also that `cache` can be helpful for the caching of a network requested observable for example.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to solve this. One more general solution would be `Observable.concat`.

```
// Our sources (left as an exercise for the reader)
Observable<Data> memory = ...;  
Observable<Data> disk = ...;  
Observable<Data> network = ...;

// Retrieve the first source with data
Observable<Data> source = Observable  
  .concat(memory, disk, network)
  .first();
```

You will need two observables for your case. If the token exists in the local storage `concat` won't subscribe to the network observable. More info in the blog post.

Code sample from [this blog post](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/06/22/loading-data-from-multiple-sources-with-rxjava/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you´re looking for, but the structured should be pretty simple

```
  Observable.just(getToken())
      .filter(token->Strings.isNullOrEmpty(token))
      .map(this::findNewToken)
      .cache() 
      .subscribe(token -> println("Your new Token")
```